# Displaying a mySQL query as a JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need JSON to appear in the below format.  Object is "users"

```
  {
    "users": [{
        "ver": "1.5",
        "name": "Cupcake",
        "api": "API level 3"
    }, {
        "ver": "7.0",
        "name": "Nougat",
        "api": "API level 24"
    }]
}
```

when I use this PHP

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Could not connect to database");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

 {
   while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

  $emparray[] = $row;

    echo json_encode($emparray);
 }

} else {
echo "It failed";
}
?>
```

I get back this JSON

```
   [{
    "ver": "1.5",
        "name": "Cupcake",
        "api": "API level 3"
}, {
    "ver": "7.0",
        "name": "Nougat",
        "api": "API level 24"
}
}]
```

When I use this PHP

```
  <?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Could not connect to database");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

 {
   while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  $emparray[] = $row;

    echo json_encode(array('users' => $emparray),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  }

} else {
echo "It failed";
}
?>
```

I get this

```
 {
    "users": {
        "0": {
            "ver": "1.5",
        "name": "Cupcake",
        "api": "API level 3"
        },
        "1": {
            "ver": "7.0",
        "name": "Nougat",
        "api": "API level 24"
        }
    }
}
```

The latter is almost what I need but displays {"0": instead of the required [ and ]

Can anyone help correct this?

Comment: `json_encode(array('users' => $emparray));`?

Comment: Works perfectly now @JonStirling .

Comment: Take the `echo json_encode()` out of the loop. You should just do it once after you've filled in the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
{
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $emparray[] = $row;
  }

  echo json_encode(array('users' => $emparray));
}
else
{
  echo "It failed";
}
```

Remove `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` constant.